# RegEx help tokenizing a string

Tags: java, regex, text

Could anyone tell me how I can take this: `(King's_Cross_St_Pancras, Farringdon, Hammersmith_&_City_Line)`

And split it into:

```
array[0]: King's_Cross_St_Pancras
array[1]: Farringdon
array[2]: Hammersmith_&_City_Line
```

The regex should also account for < > non-word characters too. I have tried to make the regex using: `"\b(<>&')?`" .. this is however completely useless.

Please help

Comment: yourString.split(", ") does exactly that; isn't that enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easier and quicker without an RegEx:

```
String str = "(King's_Cross_St_Pancras, Farringdon, Hammersmith_&_City_Line)";
String result[] = str.substring(1, str.length()-1).split(",");
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to use a regular expression here. Strip the `()` using `String.substring()`, then split the string into tokens using `String.split()`. Although technically this is also a regex solution, as `String.split()` takes a regex. :)

```
String s = "(King's_Cross_St_Pancras, Farringdon, Hammersmith_&_City_Line)";
s = s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
String tokens[] = s.split(", ");
```

Result:

```
King's_Cross_St_Pancras
Farringdon
Hammersmith_&_City_Line
```

http://ideone.com/zSDN5

Comment: @Hello71 No it isn't. You're confusing strings with arrays.

Comment: No I'm not. I'm confusing Java with JavaScript. :|

Comment: I gave answer to @atticae as it was slightly more succinct/elegant. Also he needs the points more! :)